# how to add up attributes present in two xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have these two xml ,and I want the sum of attibutes in final xml by summing them from given two inputs.Explained below in example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<chart xmlns="http://www.xyz.in/server/model" labelStep="1" showValues="0">
   <categories>
      <category Label="Bangalore Technical RATH" />
   </categories>
   <dataset>
      <set value="3" anchorRadius="2" anchorBorderThickness="3" />
      <set value="3" anchorRadius="2" anchorBorderThickness="3" />
   </dataset>
</chart>
```

similar is second input2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<chart xmlns="http://www.xyz.in/server/model" labelStep="1" showValues="0">
   <categories>
      <category Label="Bangalore Technical RATH" />
   </categories>
   <dataset>
      <set value="2" anchorRadius="2" anchorBorderThickness="3" />
      <set value="1" anchorRadius="2" anchorBorderThickness="3" />
   </dataset>
</chart>
```

Code I am using for xsl-ttransformation is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:variable name="second" select="document('file2.xml')//*[local-name()='set']" />
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='set']/@*[local-name()='value']">
      <xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name()='set']">
         <xsl:variable name="secondvalue" select="$second/@value" />
         <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:value-of select="@*[local-name()='value']  + $secondvalue[1]" />
         </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

so in final output.xml I need showing only part Interested in

```
<dataset>
       <set value="5" anchorRadius="2" anchorBorderThickness="3"/>
       <set value="4" anchorRadius="2" anchorBorderThickness="3"/>
</dataset>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:my="http://www.xyz.in/server/model" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="my:dataset">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:for-each select="my:set">
            <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()" />
            <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
               <xsl:attribute name="value">
                  <xsl:value-of select="number(@value) + number(document('source2.xml')/my:chart/my:dataset/my:set[$position]/@value)" />
               </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:copy>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @HashCoder      Your solutions is correct but actually I don't want dependencies on "my:dataset" as in input.xml dataset may be present may not be , i:e when there are multiple set then only we have tag dataset , so this code may not run if only one set is present

Comment: this is not my solution..it's @smj

Comment: Hi, you'll need to think about these questions: How many sets can there be in each file? Does input2.xml always have the same number as input1.xml, or are they different? Is input1 always have more sets than input2, or can 2 have more?

Comment: @smj the two input xml will be exactly same in terms of tags either one of kind explained in short with tags `<chart     > <categories>.. </categories><dataset..><set...></set></dataset></chart` or `<chart....> <set.. /></chart>`

Comment: @smj can we get the position() of dataset in variable .in your solution just below template match of "dataset"

Comment: Another question, if there is zero <dataset> element, is there only ever one <set> element?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the sum in cache and later when you are parsing the resultant query, you can use this cache to put the sum of the values from other 2 xmls. 
Also you can set profile attribute for the same.